# Regular Expression Exactly Two 1's

Tags: regex

I'm fairly new to using regular expressions and I've been stuck on how to make a regular expression that accepts Binary strings that contain exactly two 1's and an odd number of zeros. I have an idea of the odd zeros part 1*01*(01*01*)* but I'm not sure how to incorporate it into the exactly two 1's part.

Comment: How long can this string be? This might be better implemented as a lookup table. There are only 56 such binary strings in a 16-bit space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there is a much more efficient way, but one possibility would be:

- use `(00)*` to include any even number of zeros
- add the two ones by hand -> `(00)*1(00)*1(00)*`
- and then go through the four cases of additional zeros using OR so that the total number is odd: one additional 0 in front, in the middle or in the back or one in all of those locations

So the final regex could look like this:

```
(0(00)*1(00)*1(00)*)|((00)*1(00)*01(00)*)|((00)*1(00)*1(00)*0)|((00)0*1(00)0*1(00)*0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes I've thought about using the even number of zeros and adding an additional zero to it to make it odd but it did not seem to lead anywhere but seeing it done through three cases has definitely done the job.

Answer (score 1):

from my lecture they said the format was the characters 0* 1 0* 1 0* ?